# Exchange 2010 calendar folder permissions not applying

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I have an Exchange 2010 server (Small Business Server 2011 specifically), and I'm having trouble with calendar permissions applying correctly. User A should be able to access user B's calendar, and I can verify that the permissions are set correctly (as they always have been):

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity user.b:\Calendar

RunspaceId   : 3262277d-f110-440e-be7c-b1856cb17d0f
FolderName   : Calendar
User         : Default
AccessRights : {AvailabilityOnly}
Identity     : Default
IsValid      : True

RunspaceId   : 3262277d-f110-440e-be7c-b1856cb17d0f
FolderName   : Calendar
User         : Anonymous
AccessRights : {None}
Identity     : Anonymous
IsValid      : True

RunspaceId   : 3262277d-f110-440e-be7c-b1856cb17d0f
FolderName   : Calendar
User         : User A
AccessRights : {Editor}
Identity     : User A
IsValid      : True
```

User A can view the calendar fine. However, attempting to add or edit an event comes up with this error:

[image: asdf]

This problem is occurring for several different sets of users and calendar folders. The permissions have been working properly in the past. I've tried:

- Installing the latest Windows Updates.
- Removing the permissions and re-adding them.
- Changing the permissions (from Editor to Owner and vice versa).

What else can I try in order to diagnose this issue? Is there some simple fix I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - remember that Exchange caches permissions. Therefore if you change a permission it can take two hours before it is fully effective.

What does Outlook show for the permissions on the calendar folder?

Does it show the user listed?